# Algolia Instantsearch: pass refined values between pages

Tags: javascript, algolia

I have an two page site where the main page is a master list with 5 facets for filtering in which the results link to the second/detail page.  The detail page is a separate index but three of the facets on the master page also apply on the detail page.  I'd like to pass the values from the currentRefinedValues object to the detail page and apply those on the page load.

Any ideas on how to this may be done?

Comment: You can probably use cookies for that, but you must put what you have done until now, question is too broad.

Comment: using cookies will prevent the user from being able to bookmark the detail pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

passing the values as parameters in the query string, from the main page to the detail page. on page load of the detail page, look for values in window.location and apply those.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.